# Image from mysql database doesn't display in browser

Tags: php, mysql, image, pdo, blob

I'm trying to display an image that is stored in a MySql Database.

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE `Pictures` (
`Id` varchar(36) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
`Name` varchar(100) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
`Type` varchar(25) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
`Size` varchar(25) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
`Picture` mediumblob NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The php code haves the following structure

Repostory
- Service
- - Image.php

Repository

```
public static function GetPictureById($id) 
{
    global $db;
    $d = $GLOBALS["db"];
    $result = $d->prepare("SELECT * FROM Pictures WHERE id = :id");
    $result->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 36);

    if($result->execute() !== true)
    {
        Pre($result->errorInfo());
        return;
    }

    $result->bindColumn("Id", $id);
    $result->bindColumn("Type", $type);
    $result->bindColumn("Size", $size);
    $result->bindColumn("Picture", $picture, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    while($result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) 
    {
        $pic = new Picture();
        $pic->SetId($id);
        $pic->SetType($type);
        $pic->SetSize($size);
        $pic->SetPicture($picture);
    }

    return $pic;
}
```

Service

```
public static function GetPictureById($id) 
{
    return PictureRepository::GetPictureById($id);
}
```

Image.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/new";        
include_once($root . "/Config/Config.php");     
$picture = PictureRepository::GetPictureById($_GET["id"]);  
header("Content-type:". $picture->GetType());
echo $picture->GetPicture();
```

unfortunately IE shows a block with a red cross and Firefox tells the image contain errors

Who sees the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of `echo`.

`echo` is for printing strings. You need to write binary data to the STDOUT stream.

To do this, you need to use [`fwrite`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

Something like:

```
fwrite(STDOUT,$picture->GetPicture());
```

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect.  `echo` emits binary data without a second thought.

Answer (score 0):

Download the image (right click/save as) and then load it up in a text editor, see if there's any PHP warnings/errors at the start of the file. You've got E_ALL for error reporting, so a single syntax oddity anywhere in your scripts will spit out a warning and corrupt the data stream.

Comment: the texteditor shows a empty file but if id comment the header in the phpfile i see a not readable text. it looks like a binary file

Comment: One simple check would be to compare the downloaded file size to the size of the file as it was before it was uploaded to the database. They should be identical.

Comment: Hi Marc thanks for your help. when I'm trying to (right click/save as) I get only 'show image'(something like that). my browsers is in the dutch language